# Editing Navigation in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, error

What the heck is going on with SharePoint online today? I tried editing my left navigation and these errors display on multiple site collections Tested in Edge and Chrome

Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check after sometime. Few days before I face the same issue but automatically its gone .

Comment: Ok, Ill give it a few hours and try again